# CDO Email Automation

Tags: email, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, cdo.message

I have a MS Access 2010 db that I want to send emails from automatically.  I have the query set up but am getting stuck with the CDO VBA.  They query is called 'qryEmails' and contains the following 4 fields:

```
ReturnCode, SalesOrderNumber, Name, EmailAddress
```

How do I get Access to:

1. Loop through each record and send an email to each email address listed
2. In each email, have a message that will contain reference to the
   first 3 fields, so each message appears personalised
3. Have a dynamic subject, so the `ReturnCode` field is in each subject

I have been trying small steps at first, so far I am receiving 100's of emails to the same address.  Here is my code  (I have used XXX where I do not want to disclose info):

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strEmail As String
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
'
strSQL = "[qryEmails]"  'source of recordset
rst.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
'
Do While Not rst.EOF
    strEmail = rst.Fields("EmailAddress")

    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objMessage.Subject = "Your refund is:" '
    objMessage.FROM = """SENDER"" <XXX@somewhere.com>"
    objMessage.To = rst.Fields("EmailAddress")
    objMessage.TextBody = objMessage.TextBody & rst(1)


    '==Add fields to email body
    'Do While strEmail = rst.Fields("EmailAddress")

    'rst.MoveNext
    'If rst.EOF Then Exit Do
    'Loop

' ========= SMTP server configuration 

        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
         ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

        'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "XXX"

        'Server port (typically 25)
        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

        '==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

        'Send email
        objMessage.Send
        'Clear variable for next loop
        Set objMessage = Nothing
    Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Any idea why this is sending 100's of emails?  The query result so far is only returning two addresses for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Within the loop, the recordset remains on the same row.  And since the recordset row does not change, it never reaches `rst.EOF`

That code includes a disabled line for `MoveNext`.  Uncomment that line.  And you probably want to position it just before the `Loop` statement.

```vb
Do While Not rst.EOF
    ' do everything you need for current record,
    ' then move to the next record ...
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```