# Is there a way to make a report's caption consist of field values of this report when using Docmd.Sendobject?

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime, report, caption

I use MS-Access of Office 365. I want the caption of a report to consist of some field values on this report. For this I added VBA in the Load event of the report (Me.Caption = Me.OrdNo & " - " & Me.SalesDate) and it works.
However, if I want to send this report via email using the DoCmd.SendObject command, the report contains only the default caption value which I've added during report design.

Is there a way to make a report's caption consist of field values of this report when using DoCmd.SendObject. Specifically, that the load event fires while using Docmd.Sendobject?

Comment: Maybe use OutputTo to save as PDF then use Outlook automation to created email with attached file.

Comment: I just did a test of SendObject. The report border is not rendered in the PDF so how could report Caption display?

Comment: I want users without MS-Office but with the Access runtime library to be able to use the application. DoCmd.SendOject uses the installed email client and it doesn't necessarily have to be Outlook. DoCmd.SendObject seemed like a suitable solution for that.

Comment: Me.Caption appears to be used as the file name of the generated PDF when using < DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, ..,.. >. My question concerns whether there is a possibility to make that file name consist of specific field values (Me.Caption = Me.OrdNo & " - " & Me.SalesDate) of the generated report.

Comment: I think only if the report property is changed in design and saved. VBA can open report in design view, change property, save with change, then send. Alternative is OutputTo to save PDF with desired name and CDO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611934/cdo-email-automation) code to create email and attach PDF.

Comment: More info on CDO https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=send-email-access-vba-cdo, https://blueclawdb.com/access-database/tutorials/access-email-gmail/.

Comment: June7, thanks for your replies. I'll see if I can get cdo mail up and running. So far I haven't been able to do that. Something with google and access for third party apps is preventing cdo mail from working. Hence I pinned my hopes on DoCmd.SendObject. Too bad that the name of the generated PDF report cannot be changed during runtime.